# Selenium Xunit c# IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver()) does not open a browser - it opens a CMD window

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xunit.net

I have a Selenium test project that's up and working find and now I need another project to use Selenium. So I installed all of the same NuGet packages as the other project and started writing code, but right away in the first few lines I have an issue. As soon as it executes this line of code a CMD window opens (see below), a browser opens for a second and then shuts and control never passes on the the next line in my program.

```
using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver())
```

[image]

What could I be doing wrong? Seems pretty simple and it works in my other project. If I can't figure this out maybe I'll just gut the other project of most of it's code and put my new code in a copy. But this shouldn't be complicated.

Answering the first question I got below, it's a Windows forms app. I didn't initially know I'd be needing Selenium so I tried adding it after the fact. I was hoping that adding all of the NuGet packages I could add Selenium/xUnit functionality. If that just won't work I'll have to come up with something else. I need to go to a website and click on some links and thought Selenium would be the easiest way to do that.

Here's the Using section:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Text;
using System.Timers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Management;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;
using Xunit;
```

Comment: What kind of project did you add? Can you please include the body of the `using` block? Which version of Chrome are you running? We cannot answer your question without a [repro].

Comment: @GregBurghardt I updated the initial post with more info. As for a minimally reproducible example, using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver()) is it. That's the one line of code I'm executing and seeing this behavior.

Comment: Hm. Which version of ChromeDriver are you using? Which version of chrome are you using? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Was the other working project a unit test project or WinForms?

Comment: @GregBurghardt I'm not using ChromeDriver - I'm using FirefoxDriver. And I tried every browser - Chrome, Firefox, Edge and IE and get the same results with all of them. The original project was a unit test project. I've given up and just stripped down the original project and written new code to do what I need done. I'll just call it with vstest.console.exe. Not how I envisioned this working, but it will work.